# image was taken by UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera how to save it in database in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

coding in .m

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

} else {
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        UIAlertView *noCameraAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                message:@"You don't have a camera for this device" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        //shows above alert if there's no camera
        [noCameraAlert show];
    }else{
        picker.sourceType    = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.delegate      = self;
    }
}
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
     UIImage *img     = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
img              = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image  = img;
imagData         = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

the image was placed in Image view now how can i save the image in database

I'm already having the database to insert the data
To Insert:

```
NSMutableArray *listItemsarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if([listItemsarr count]==0){
            NSString *insertQry=@"INSERT INTO selection_tbl (expenses_value,category,date,payment,description) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt=[DB OpenSQL:[insertQry UTF8String]];
            if(stmt !=nil)
            {
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,1, [dataTextfield.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,2, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:0]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,3, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:1]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,4, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:2]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,5, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:3]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


                sqlite3_step(stmt);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            [DB CloseSQL];
```

The following coding is use to update the database values
To Update:

```
NSInteger proeditid = [primarykeyID integerValue];
        NSString *updateQry=@"update selection_tbl set expenses_value=?,category=?,date=?,payment=?,description=? where expenses_id=?";
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt=[DB OpenSQL:[updateQry UTF8String]];
        if(stmt !=nil)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,1, [dataTextfield.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,2, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:0] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,3, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:1] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,4, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:2] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,5, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:3] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


            sqlite3_bind_int(stmt,6, (int)proeditid);
            sqlite3_step(stmt);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        [DB CloseSQL];
```

Comment: but can you please tell me how to add Image which was taken by UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera into database alone?

Comment: By the way, three snaps for proper use of the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions. So many people incorrectly use `stringWithFormat` to build their SQL, so it's nice to see someone properly binding values to `?` placeholders. Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line in your code which will add the image in your database

```
 sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt,6, [imagData bytes], (unsigned)[imagData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Final code will looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray *listItemsarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            if([listItemsarr count]==0){
                NSString *insertQry=@"INSERT INTO selection_tbl (expenses_value,category,date,payment,description,image) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                sqlite3_stmt *stmt=[DB OpenSQL:[insertQry UTF8String]];
                if(stmt !=nil)
                {
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,1, [dataTextfield.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,2, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:0]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,3, [dateString  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,4, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:2]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,5, [[selectionarray objectAtIndex:3]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt,6, [imagData bytes], (unsigned)[imagData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                    sqlite3_step(stmt);
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
                [DB CloseSQL];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions:

1. How to get the `NSData` representation of the image?

   - The easy approach is to use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` of the `UIImage`.
   - The better approach is to use `getBytes` to retrieve the raw asset. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251943/1271826.
2. How to save the `NSData` representation in a SQLite database?

   To save this `NSData` in your database, you then use `sqlite3_bind_blob`. The process is very similar to the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions that you shared with us earlier. Use the `bytes` method of `NSData` to access the C-style pointer to the buffer, and pass that to `sqlite3_bind_blob`.

Note, saving full size images in a SQLite database is notoriously inefficient. SQLite doesn't handle large blobs well. Generally people would prefer to save the `NSData` into a file in the Documents folder on the device's persistent storage, and then just save the `path` of that file in the database.

Comment: check out my question now hope it will be easy to understand now

Comment: Putting code in the question rather than comments is much better. Thanks. I hope my answer is equally clear: First get `NSData` representation of the image (using either of those two techniques I discuss above), and then use `bytes` and `length` methods of the resulting `NSData` and pass those to the `sqlite3_bind_blob` function.

Comment: sure sir will do it soon Thank you so much for your reply @Rob