# UIImageJPEGRepresentation using large amount of memory (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to compress and get the NSdata from between 20 and 30 UIImages with a "for-loop" like this:

```
for theImage in selectedUIImages {

let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.5)
// doing something with the data

}
```

Tried on an iPhone 7 with no issues besides my app using upto 700MB of memory when going through the loop, but on an older iPhone I get the message:

```
*Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue.*
```

The main objective is to get the NSData from the UIImage so I can put the image in a dir for uploading. Let me explain:

The Amazon S3 Transfer utility wants a path/url to the image and therefore I need to make a path/url for the UIImage and the only way i know is to get it by:

```
data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: localPath), options: .atomic)
```

Comment: Did you try it in device ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248294/uiimagejpegrepresentation-received-memory-warning.

Comment: Priyal: What do u mean?

Comment: Martin: This is for swift 3.0

Comment: @NSNoob Thx for asking mate :-) let me explain.

The Amazon S3 Transfer utility wants a path/url to the image and therefor i need to make a path/url for the UIimage and the only way i know is to get it by: data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: localPath), options: .atomic)

Comment: @fayyaz See now this is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Your main problem is figuring out the path to a image, not moving them in a loop to documents directory.

Comment: i see what you mean :-)

Comment: @fayyaz I would suggest using Photos Framework and see [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025487/nsurl-from-phasset) question on getting file path from the PHAsset. It will save you memory and processing power

Comment: @fayyaz how you solved this facing same issue

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora When using PHImageManager.default().requestImage i used targetsize to get the images with smaller widht and height instead of the big originals. it saved me a lot of memory

Answer (score 1):

Try using an autorelease pool:

```
autoreleasepool {
    for theImage in selectedUIImages {

        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.5)
        // doing something with the data

     }
}
```

and move it in a background thread.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to have the autoreleasepool inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Because your app run out of memory.
You can save it to Document directory after compress then upload it to server one by one. So it not make your memory issue.

Comment: So it would be better to first compress then upload. So basically 1. a for-loop that compresses and then another that uploades?

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the image size by decreasing a ratio parameter. You can use 0.3 instead 0.5.

```
for theImage in selectedUIImages {

let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.3)
// doing something with the data

}
```

Comment: same error as before :(

*Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue.*

Comment: @fayyaz You will keep getting that message because you have no control over the number of images in selectedUIImages array. It may work for a number of images and start crashing on just one more image than that.