# ScreenShot is too large when taken in high resolution iOS devices

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I take a screenshot for a full screen size view in high resolution iOS devices, the result image data is very large. For example, the resolution of iPhoneX is 812*375, and screen scale is 3. Thus, a ARGB image for a full screenshot will take about 812*3 * 375*3 * 4 bytes, aka 10.4MB. So when I use these screenshot images in my app, the memory usage will jump to a high level, and maybe trigger a memory warning.

Here is my code:

```
if (CGRectIsEmpty(self.bounds)) {
        return nil;
}
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds
           afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *renderImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Even if I compress the screenshot image, there is still some pulses in memory usages.

[image]

So my question is: Is there any good way to take a high resolution screenshot and avoid memory pressure?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problems while working with images - memory usage can be extreme causing memory warnings and crashes, especially if using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` method on older devices (iPhone 4). So I tried to avoid using this method by saving pictures to Gallery and fetching them afterwards, this does not help much though, memory jumps persist anyway.

I suppose "pulses" are caused by copying the whole data to memory during converting. Possible solution would be to implement custom disk caching and decoding mechanism so the data could be processed in chunks, but still don't know if it worth to do. For me this problem still persists, maybe [following list](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#image) could be helpful.

Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248294/uiimagejpegrepresentation-received-memory-warning) question.

Other solution is to free view controllers resources in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method if possible.